# How to find if following function is Convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I want to optimize the following function $U = ...$ using KKT. I am still learning KKT. However, I cannot understand how I can find if the following function is a convex function?

$$U = \frac{(A-1)B\ln(B) - A\ln(A)B + A\ln(A)}{(A-1)(B-1)(B-A)}.$$

$$A = \Big(\frac{r}{p}\Big)^{\alpha}\Big(\frac{P_a}{P_x}\Big)$$and

$$B = \Big(\frac{r}{q}\Big)^{\alpha}\Big(\frac{P_{b}}{P_x}\Big)\varepsilon$$.

where $\varepsilon \in[0,1], \frac{r}{p},\frac{r}{q} <1$ and $r,p,q \in \mathbb{R}$ and are determined by an algirthm I have developed. $\alpha = [2,4]$, lets assume $\varepsilon = 0.1,\alpha = 2$ for the current scenario (If this info in important).

$P_a,P_b,P_x \leq 1$.

Note that $P_a$ and $P_b$ are constants and I have to control $P_x$ to optimize.

Comment: So you want to know if $U$ is convex as a function of $P_x$?

Comment: oh... Yes, I mean the same but I never thought it this way earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but to help you investigate yourself further:

Let's simplify the notation. Define

$$ c_A\equiv\bigg(\frac{r}{p}\bigg)^\alpha P_a $$

$$ c_B\equiv\bigg(\frac{r}{q}\bigg)^\alpha P_b\varepsilon$$

Then your specified function $U$ is

$$ U(x)=\frac{\big(\frac{c_A}{x}-1\big)\frac{c_B}{x}\log\big(\frac{c_B}{x}\big)-\big(\frac{c_B}{x}-1\big)\frac{c_A}{x}\log\big(\frac{c_A}{x}\big)}{\big(\frac{c_A}{x}-1\big)\big(\frac{c_B}{x}-1\big)\big(\frac{c_B-c_A}{x}\big)} $$

which can be simplified to

$$ U(x)=\frac{x}{c_B-c_A}\bigg(\frac{c_B\log(c_B/x)}{c_B-x}-\frac{c_A\log(c_A/x)}{c_A-x}\bigg) $$

where I have replaced your notation $P_x$ with the letter $x$, to make things a little clearer. The function may be easier to investigate in this form.